# Rail API - Disable cached response

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching, no-cache

I have a `Rails 6 API`-only application and I'm using `Nginx` and `passenger`.

When I try to do `GET` or `POST` in the Postman application or other places, I get only cached responses.

For instance, if I try to get **user 1**, movies, I'll get the correct ones, but if I change the `JWT` to **user 2**, I still see the previous response which was for `user 1`.

I have tried a few options such as:

In `production.rb` I added:

```
config.action_controller.perform_caching = false
config.cache_store = :null_store
```

I have also tried the `controller` level by adding: `expires_now` which in the header shows `no-cache` and also with `expires_in 5.seconds, public: false` which shows `max-age=5, private` as the header, but I still get the same response for any user.

Comment: Could you please also share controller code.

Comment: @SampatBadhe the controller code has only `expires_now ` and its very straight forward: `@movies = current_user.movies`

Comment: I hope `expires_now` is called from `before_action` and not from the actual action.

Comment: @SampatBadhe its called from the actual action. Should it in the controller itself or the `ApplicationController`?

Answer (score 0):

you can use a command to disable cache in rails app: rails dev:cache